# Running Apple Script on hidden safari window

Tags: macros, safari, applescript

I am running apple script. 
My problem is that i am opening a safari window using apple script. 
After that I am hiding it using script 
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari" to set visible to false

Now I want that my leftover script should run on that safari window which is hidden, but when i hide safari window then the focus to the safari is lost and the script starts running on the application that has focus instead of safari window.

Can we do this? Please tell the solution if we can.Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a 'tell application "Safari" - block to talk to Safari.app -

Comment: Can you give me an example.

Comment: Basically it's this: put all the code that belongs to Safari in a 'tell application "Safari" ... [ your code ] end tell - block.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with the window? If I hide Safari with an open window, I can still access the window using the normal tell block, like

```
tell application "Safari"
    set bounds of window 1 to {111, 222, 777, 666}
end tell
```

with no problem. But perhaps you are using System Events, which may not be necessary (and possibly bad practice) but it depends on what you're trying to do. Check Safari's dictionary, and post example code.

Comment: This is hiding all the safari windows. I want that my apple script should run on hidden safari window.

Comment: Please update your question to explain how you are hiding a single window. It is not very clear hence you are not getting the answers you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
tell application "System Events" to set visible of process "Safari" to false
```

Comment: This apple script is not running on hidden safari window, its running in the any other application window that is focused. I want it to run on hidden safari window.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
tell application "Safari"
activate
delay 1
tell application "System Events" to set visible of process "Safari" to false
```